# Saving all the rows in oracle table when the checkbox is selected and save button is clicked in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, insert, save, rows

I need to write a stored procedure in Oracle PLSQL to save multiple rows at once in a table.

In the below UI, each row has 4 fields with one of the fields having a Checkbox. When the checkbox is selected and the Save button is clicked then that particular row has to be saved in the Oracle table "Authorization". Multiple checkboxes in various rows can be selected and clicked on Save Button and all those rows need to be saved in the table.

UI screen :

Include  |    flight        |   location      | status

[image]

1) In UI screen, we can see that two rows are selected. When the Save button is clicked then Based on the checkboxes selected, those records need to be saved in the below table.

Table AUTHORIZATION:

**Flight      |        Location    |    Status   |    INCLUDED**
United        |          Burbank    |      Late   |       Y
KLM Royal Airlines|     Buffalo     |     Late     |     Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no problem to insert a number of rows into a table via a PL/SQL procedure. Probably the best way is to pass a collection and then use FORALL to push them in with a minimum of context switches and maximum performance.

The trick for you is to load up the collection in whatever front end environment you are using to allow the users to select specific rows on the screen.

Here's some code to give you an idea of what to do:

```
CREATE TABLE trees
(
   tree_id     NUMBER,
   tree_name   VARCHAR2 (100)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE tree_mgr
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   TYPE trees_t IS TABLE OF trees%ROWTYPE;

   PROCEDURE ins_trees (trees_in IN trees_t);
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY tree_mgr
IS
   PROCEDURE ins_trees (trees_in IN trees_t)
   IS
   BEGIN
      FORALL indx IN INDICES OF trees_in
         INSERT INTO trees (tree_id, tree_name)
              VALUES (trees_in (indx).tree_id, trees_in (indx).tree_name);
   END;
END;
/

DECLARE
   l_trees   tree_mgr.trees_t := tree_mgr.trees_t ();
BEGIN
   l_trees.EXTEND (2);
   l_trees (1).tree_id := 100;
   l_trees (1).tree_name := 'Oak';
   l_trees (2).tree_id := 101;
   l_trees (2).tree_name := 'Elm';
   tree_mgr.ins_trees (l_trees);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertProcedure(isSelect in varchar2 ) return varchar2 is
BEGIN
if isSelect is not null then
FOR r IN
  (SELECT AUT.Flight,AUT.Location,AUT.Status,AUT.INCLUDED 
FROM AUTHORIZATION AUT) 
 LOOP 
  BEGIN
   IF r.somecol = 0  -- SOME IF conditions .
    INSERT INTO yourInsertTable(col1,col2,col3,col4)
    VALUES (r.col1,r.col2,r.col3,r.col4);
   END IF;
   EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  --block_to_log_error;
  END; 
 END;
 END LOOP;
 else 
  //what do you want
 end if;
  exception
  when others then null;
   return 'xxx';
END;
```

Your need like this procedure and this may work or may have some syntax errors. Let me know if you get it to work or get error.